# Constructing a circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose two arbitrary vectors $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$ and $y\in \mathbb{C}^n$ are given. Consider determining a circulant $C\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ such that $$y = Cx$$
>
> a.) Assume that $C$ exists for a given pair $(x,y)$, show how to construct it.
>
> b.) When is $C$ unique for a given pair $(x,y)$
>
> c.) When does $C$ not exist for a given pair of $(x,y)$

Note - $F$ is the unitary matrix representing the DFT and $\Lambda\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is a diagonal matrix

Attempted solution a.) - The relationship of the eigendecompostion of $C$ to the DFT gives a simple and elegant view of the problem in the Fourier domain, i.e., the eigensdomain. We have \begin{align*} 
Cx &= y\\
F\Lambda F^H x & = y\\
\Lambda F^H x &= F^H y\\
\Lambda x &= F^H y F\\
x &= \Lambda^{-1}F^H y F
\end{align*}

Attempted solution b.) If we suppose that $A$ and $B$ are given matrices and we further suppose that $ y = Ax = Bx$ then if we show that $A = B$ does that suffice to show that $C$ is unique?

I am not sure if I am right any suggestions is greatly appreciated for a,b, and c.

Comment: I suspect you are taking an overly complicated route to part (a).  The $n\times n$ circulant matrx $C$ is determined by $n$ unknowns, say $c_k = C_{i,j}$ where $k \equiv i-j \bmod{n}$.  Write out the conditions for $c_k$ to satsify $Cx = y$ and see what kind of equations you have to solve.

Comment: I don't see how it is complicated would you like me to show you how $C = F\Lambda F^H$ for clarity purposes?

Comment: Since it requires you to "show how to construct it", I'd prefer to stick to the $n$ unknowns that directly define the entries of $C$.  Of course you may prefer to account for the larger number of unknowns needed to define $C$ by $F\Lambda F^H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if we define $n$ unknowns $c_k$, for $k=0,\ldots,n-1$ such that the entry $C_{i,j}$ of $n\times n$ circulant matrix $C$ is $c_k$ for $k\equiv i-j \bmod{n}$, then:

$$ C=
\begin{bmatrix}
c_0     & c_{n-1} & \dots  & c_{2} & c_{1}  \\
c_{1} & c_0    & c_{n-1} &         & c_{2}  \\
\vdots  & c_{1}& c_0    & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
c_{n-2}  &        & \ddots & \ddots  & c_{n-1}   \\
c_{n-1}  & c_{n-2} & \dots  & c_{1} & c_0 \\
\end{bmatrix}  $$

Now the requirement that $Cx=y$ for given (complex) vectors $x,y$ amounts to a system of $n$ linear equations for the $n$ unknowns $c_k$.  Simply put, we can determine the solution for $C$ by solving for the $c_k$ in this linear system, since it merely restates the condition that $Cx = y$, as desired.

A little thought shows that the actual matrix form of this linear system again involves a circulant matrix $X$ such that:

$$ X \begin{pmatrix} c_0 \\ \vdots \\ c_{n-1} \end{pmatrix} = y $$

where:

$$ X = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1     & x_n & \dots  & x_3 & x_2  \\
x_2 & x_1    & x_n &         & x_3  \\
\vdots  & x_2 & x_1   & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
x_{n-1}  &        & \ddots & \ddots  & x_n   \\
x_n  & x_{n-1} & \dots  & x_{2} & x_1 \\
\end{bmatrix}  $$

So the answer to part (b) amounts to the condition that $X$ is invertible, thus making the solution to $Cx=y$ *unique*.  It also gives us insight into how to arrange that $X$ is not invertible and hence solutions may not be unique (or may not exist, which is your part (c)).

**Example**

Since this approach seemingly switches the role of $C$ with circulant matrix $X$, a small worked example may help the Reader see that what is happening can be discovered by following a standard line of investigation.

Suppose $x = y = (1,2,3)^T$.  Clearly $C=I$ satisfies the requirment that $Cx=y$, but we show how the analysis above proves this is a unique solution in this particular case.  Writing out the general $3\times 3$ system of equations for entries of $C$:

$$  \begin{align*} 
c_0 x_1 + c_2 x_2 + c_1 x_3 &= y_1 \\
c_1 x_1 + c_0 x_2 + c_2 x_3 &= y_2 \\
c_2 x_1 + c_1 x_2 + c_0 x_3 &= y_3 \end{align*}  $$

Rearranging the terms so that the unknowns $c_i$ are ordered:

$$  \begin{align*} 
c_0 x_1 + c_1 x_3 + c_2 x_2 &= y_1 \\
c_0 x_2 + c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_3 &= y_2 \\
c_0 x_3 + c_1 x_2 + c_2 x_1 &= y_3 \end{align*}  $$

we arrive at the reversal of roles for $X$ and $C$:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_3 & x_2 \\ x_2 & x_1 & x_3 \\ x_3 & x_2 & x_1 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c_0 \\ c_1 \\ c_2 \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \end{pmatrix} $$

Substitute the known values from $x,y$ and we have the specific system:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c_0 \\ c_1 \\ c_2 \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} $$

The coefficient matrix $X$ here is nonsingular since $\det X = 18$, so the solution $c_0 = 1$ and $c_1 = c_2 = 0$ is unique.  Thus $C=I$ is the only possibility for a circulant matrix that makes $Cx=y$.

Comment: For part a.) by your answer we solve for the elements of $C$ when we are given $x$ and $y$ so are you saying that by doing so we just solve a system of linear equations?

Comment: Also from the answer I provided we can construct  $C$ with the DFT matrix $F$ and a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$. Since $F$ is unitary and $\Lambda$ is just a diagonal matrix they are both invertible thus would that make $Cx = y$ unique?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Notice that part (a) says to assume a solution exists.  So solving the linear system $X\vec c = y$ gives us (at least) one solution.

Comment: Until you have $C$, you don't have $F$ or $\Lambda$.  Uniqueness of the solution depends on $x$ and the invertibility of the circulant matrix $X$ derived from it.

Comment: In case you are interested my professor provided a solution where he uses $F$ and $\Lambda$ would you like to see it?

Comment: Sure, why not post it as an Answer?

Comment: Sure thing will do

Comment: why are the elements of $X$ different from $C$?

Comment: Bear in mind the vectors $x$ and $y$ are given as *known* values, while $C $ is the unknown to be found in part (a). As an easy exercise, let $x=y=(1,2,3)^T $ and solve for circulant $C $.

Comment: Ok, perhaps I am still highly confused as usual. Since we are given $x$ and $y$ we simply have to solve for a system of linear equations to find the elements of $C$? Thus we have our $C x = y$?

Comment: You will see the difference between $C $ and $X $ if you do this exercise (just responding to the previous comment, what is the difference).

Comment: Ok, I will give it a shot. How did you think of doing it this way?

Answer (score 0):

This is my professors solution that I do not really understand fully (forgive me for not writing it out):

[image]

Comment: A minor discrepancy: your professor expressed $C = F^H \Lambda F$ where you wrote $C = F \Lambda F^H$.  The discrete Fourier transform is unitary with the right scaling, so the expression for $C$ gives us a unitary diagonalization, i.e. the eigenvalues of $C$ appear in the diagonal matrix $\Lambda$.  Once the diagonalization is performed, the solution of $\Lambda \tilde x = \tilde y$ can be done "by inspection.  Solution is unique precisely when all the diagonal entries of $C$ are nonzero, and the system is inconsistent if some $\lambda_i = 0$ where $\tilde y_i \neq 0$.

Comment: My objection to this as a complete solution is as before:  until we have $C$ to apply the diagonalization to, we don't know what its eigenvalues $\Lambda$ will consist of.  Of course it provides an observation that could be combined with my reformulation as solving $X\vec c = y$, and applying the discrete Fourier transform diagonalization to circulant matrix $X$ rather than to (unknown) circulant matrix $C$.

Comment: Based on the remark about "two basic lines of reasoning", I suspect there is more to the professor's solution.  This seems to be just one prong of the approach.

Comment: I see your point I think he did that intentionally as he does not want to provide the full detailed solution